# Xpath select cell in table being in last row in fixed column position

Tags: xpath

How can I use XPath to click a button in a table in a specific position? The column is constant and it is always the last row. I have the id of the table, but the cell contains a delete button, whose value is dynamic - a generated hash value.

```
Xpath = ".//[@=id='blah']/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]" # <- this xpath fails.
```

This is for automation - python using the selenium.

Answer (score 16):

You can also do this way using only `last()` function :

```
Xpath = ".//*[@=id='blah']//tr[last()]/td[5]"
```

Answer (score 9):

Try using xpath function `position()` and `last()`:

```
Xpath = ".//[@=id='blah']/tbody/tr[position()=last()]/td[5]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one using the last() method:

XPath = $x("`//table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[position()=last()]/td[1]`")